# ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'float' but got 'double'

Tags: python-2.7, cython

I compiled a Cython script and run it.
When running it I got  an error from the following line of code:

```
cdef np.ndarray[float] vola = np.empty(n, dtype=float)
```

Why is that? I want to fill the array vola with float values later on, so I want to format it as float, not double.

Answer (score 8):

Just use `cdef np.ndarray[double] vola = np.empty(n, dtype=float)`.

Example in ipython with cythonmagic (see an example [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/3607712653c66d63e0d7f13f073bde8c0f209ba8/docs/examples/notebooks/cython_extension.ipynb)):

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cpdef foo(n):
    cdef np.ndarray[double] vola = np.empty(n, dtype=float)
    return vola

foo(4)  #output :
array([ 2.14079666e-314, 2.14079666e-314, 2.17357252e-314, 2.78136356e-309])
```

This happens because a `numpy` float is a `C` `double`.

EDIT: for a more portable/mantainable code, you may use `np.float64_t` instead of `double`, and specify `dtype=np.float64` in the call to `empty()`.